# How to prevent tabnavigator to navigating when use horizontal scrollview

Tags: react-native

I am stuck in little problem that is i have used tab navigator in one screen and used stack navigator to achieve this.

But i have used horizontal scrollview here so whenever i scroll and it comes to end so at that time navigator is also changed and it redirected to new screen.

So is there any way to prevent navigator to navigate to another screen while scrolling.

Comment: Could you post you code? How are you handling navigation to another screen on horizontal scroll?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set following option in `Navigator` (in routes.js)

```
navigationOptions: {
  gesturesEnabled: false
}
```

reference:

[Disable swipe back action in stack navigation (react-navigation)](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1063)